# column span of a orthogonalized matrix is the same as the one of the original matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry, orthogonality, orthonormal

Consider a $n \times n$ matrix $G$. Transform the column vector into an orthonormal basis by using the Gramm-Schmidt procedure, this produces a new matrix $Q$. Under which conditions is the column span (i.e, the image) generated by the first $m <n$ columns of $G$ same as the column span generated by the first $m$ columns of  $Q$?

Comment: Are the columns of $G$ linearly independent?

Comment: In the Gram-Schmidt process, each $v_m'$ is a linear combination of $v_m$ and the $v_j'$ for $j<m$, so, yes, the spans don't change.